# Cannot set breakpoint in ocamldebug: "Can't find any event there."

Tags: debugging, ocaml, breakpoints

I'm using ocamldebug (with OCaml 4.02.1), and I'm trying to set a breakpoint somewhere inside a specific module, but all I get is a mildly useful error message: `Can't find any event there.`

As an example, here's an extract of a function<sup>1</sup> where I'd like to set a breakpoint, as listed by ocamldebug:

```
(ocd) list Value.Eval_slevel 79 83
79
80    let slevel stmt = match slevel with
81      | Per_stmt_slevel.Global i -> i
82      | Per_stmt_slevel.PerStmt f -> f stmt
83
```

I tried several variants of the `break` command, but I got the same result every time:

```
(ocd) break @ Value.Eval_slevel 80       // module + line number
Can't find any event there.
(ocd) break @ Value.Eval_slevel 80 21    // module + line + column
Can't find any event there.
(ocd) break @ Value.Eval_slevel # 3335   // module + character number
Can't find any event there.
```

I also tried nearby source lines (to check for possible line mismatches), and I also tried using module synonyms (e.g. `Eval_slevel`, `eval_slevel`), but to no avail.

Note that, if I manually step the program until it reaches this function, it shows that there is indeed an event at line 80:

```
Time: 17447400 - pc: 3865360 - module Value.Eval_slevel
80    let slevel stmt = <|b|>match slevel with
```

And, in this case, I can manually set a local breakpoint:

```
(ocd) break
Breakpoint 1 at 3865360: file src/value/eval_slevel.ml, line 80,
  characters 22-119
```

But obviously the idea is to be able to do it without having to manually find it.

If I try setting the breakpoint using the function name, ocamldebug cannot see it. Even after running the program past that event, the identifier does not seem visible to ocamldebug:

```
(ocd) break Value.Eval_slevel.slevel
Unbound identifier Value.Eval_slevel.slevel
```

Is that the reason why I cannot set the breakpoint? If so, is there a workaround? Otherwise, is there another way to set these breakpoints?

**Notes**

Here are some other things I tried doing, and some observations:

- Setting breakpoints on similar files and functions: I also obtain `Can't find any event there.`, but there are files in which it does work.
- The error is not due to an incorrect module name, otherwise ocamldebug responds with `No source file for <module>`.
- The error is not due to a non-existing line number, otherwise it says `Position out of range.`
- The error is not a module initialization issue, since the message in this case is: `The module path <module> is not yet initialized. Please run program forward until its initialization code is executed.`

<sup>1</sup> This example comes from Frama-C and it is reproducible, in case someone would be interested. However I could not produce a minimal example outside of that code base.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the Value module via dynlink by any chance? I know [this issue](https://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6792) has been open for some time and would certainly apply to OCAML 4.02.1. If that is the case, you would have to disable dynlink and link statically in order to get ocamldebug to work with that module.

Comment: Good point, but It is more like an elaboration than an answer. The *comments* section may be a better fit.